# How do I take an AWS Cognito User pool backup using my AWS user account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, backup

I need to take a backup of an existing AWS Cognito user pool to my AWS User account.

Is there any process or services from AWS that will help me achieve this?

I have gone through some of the blogs and could not find any specific solutions.